# Compiling JAVA project and creating JAR by command line

Tags: java, jar

until now, I created a (Runnable) JAR file by using Eclipse and I ran it from command line by using `java -jar File.jar`.

Now, I need to perform compiling by command line.

My project uses external libraries and consists of several packages

```
lib (all JARs imported in the code)
src
---> it
     ---> myApp
     ------------> MainPackage
     ------------> Package2
     ------------> Package3
```

Each package contains some classes, and the MainClass is in MainPackage.

Anyone can suggest me all the steps to be followed for creating the JAR file?

Thanks in advance

Comment: See [Lesson: Packaging Programs in JAR Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/) in Oracle's Java Tutorials.

Comment: Possible repeat: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16198409/how-to-create-a-runnable-jar-file-from-command-line-similar-to-eclipse